# Is there a (romantic?) story with a purple beach with silver sky and three blue moons?

Tags: story-identification, planets, mercedes-lackey

Is there a (romantic?) story with being referenced by 2004's [The Fairy Godmother](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13982.The_Fairy_Godmother), given its habit of referencing various stories, although usually fairy tales, but is this romantic / erotic dream's setting one of the more modern references?

> She did not often dream, or at least, she did not often dream in ways that could be linked back to the real world. That was deliberate; the dreams of a Godmother had the potential to take on a life of their own, and one of the things that Bella had taught her was how to dream in pleasant nonsense. So when her dream began, and she found herself walking along *a shore of purple sand by an amethyst sea beneath a silver sky with three azure moons* in it, she felt quite relaxed and comfortable. So comfortable, that she did not in the least mind when she realized that Alexander was walking beside her.